# Python ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pygame

I recently downloaded and installed pygame. I tested it with the following code.

```
import pygame
```

I received the following error:

```
C:\Python34>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in     <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I currently have Python 3.4 32 bit and have downloaded pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2 and installed it. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using 64 bit Python?

Comment: No, 32 bit. I'll include that in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame doesn't work for Python 3.4. The pygame that you downloaded is for Python 3.2. If you download Python 3.2, you should be able to use pygame.

Comment: Thank you :) are there any significant differences between 3.4 and 3.2?